# Как сравнить HTML код на Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
 var lightchecker;


 $.post("http://bruno.ru/dist-material-tf/v1.3/checker.php", function(data) {
   $("thead").html(data);
   setInterval(function() {
     lightchecker = $("thead").html();
     $.post("http://bruno.ru/dist-material-tf/v1.3/checker.php", function(data) {

       if (lightchecker == data) {
         $("thead").html(data)
         console.log(lightchecker + " равны " + data)
       } else {
         console.log(lightchecker + " неравны " + data)
       };
     });
   }, 5000)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table no-margin">
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>


  </tbody>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1qazrhh/3/)

пробую сравнить две переменных в которых содержится фрагмент html кода, но результат всегда отрицательный , хотя при ручном сравнений строки кода идентичны ... Что делаю не так? почему результат отрицательный?

Comment: HTML-код, полученый из браузерного DOM, собран им с нуля и может отличаться от оригинала в некоторых деталях вроде кавычек, слэшей или порядка атрибутов, выбираемых браузером по вкусу и стандартам. Поэтому для подобных сравнений его использовать нельзя (или же нужно каким-то образом нормализовать оба html-кода)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные на странице и те, что вы получаете с сервера не сильно, но различаются. Очень легко в этом убедиться, просто посмотрев на длину строк.
[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1qazrhh/4/) для наглядности.

Вообще, получать с сервера готовый html не самая лучшая идея. 
Намного проще будет работать с данными в формате json.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '//jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: {
    json: JSON.stringify([{
      id: 3,
      type: 'Звонок',
      manager: 'Вася',
      user: 'Олег',
      status: '',
      site: 'UBTN',
      time: '2014-04-29'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      type: 'Звонок',
      manager: 'Николай',
      user: 'Сергей',
      status: '',
      site: 'UBTN',
      time: '2014-05-30'
    }]),
    delay: 1
  },
}).done(function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data.json);
  var container = document.getElementById('exampleGrid');
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css">
<script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<div id="exampleGrid" class="dataTable"></div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1qazrhh/5/)

Подробнее с форматом можно ознакомиться на [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) или [json.org](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html)